# foldRight() based filter() overflows

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

Following example in Chap#5 of the book "Functional Programming in Scala", I implemented the lazy lists and tested it by trying to find primes in Fibonacci series. The default implementation as given in the book (on which my implementation is based) stackoverflows. However if I change the implementation of filter() function from the one based on foldRight to one using pattern matching, the stackoverflow problem is resolved. Why should this be the case?

1) The main function: 
The filter_overflow() is implemented using foldRight and overflows.
The filter() is implemented using pattern matching and does not overflow.

```
package example

object Hello {
  import datastructures._
  import datastructures.LazyList._
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  def fibs: LazyList[BigInt] =
      LazyList[BigInt](0, 1) append unfold[(BigInt, BigInt), BigInt]((0, 1))(_ match { case (a, b) => (a + b, (b, a + b)) })
    println(fibs.filter(_.isProbablePrime(8)).drop(BigInt(21)).headOrElse(-1))
    println(fibs.filter_overflow(_.isProbablePrime(8)).drop(BigInt(21)).headOrElse(-1))
 }
}
```

2) LazyList implementation:

```
package datastructures

sealed trait LazyList[+A] {
  import LazyList.{empty, cons, join, unit}
  def toList: List[A] = this.foldRight(List[A]())(_ :: _)
  def head: A = this match {
    case Cons(h, _) => h()
  }
  def headOrElse[B >: A](default: B): B = this match {
    case Empty => default
    case Cons(h, _) => h()
  }
  def tail: LazyList[A] = this match {
    case Cons(h, t) => t()
  }
  def map[B](f: A => B): LazyList[B] =
    this.foldRight(empty[B])((a, bs) => cons(f(a), bs))
  def flatMap[B](f: A => LazyList[B]): LazyList[B] =
    join(this map f)
  def foldRight[B](z: => B)(f: (A, => B) => B): B = this match {
    case Empty => z
    case Cons(h, t) => f(h(), t().foldRight(z)(f))
  }
  def append[B >: A](that: => LazyList[B]): LazyList[B] =
    this.foldRight(that)(cons(_, _))
  @annotation.tailrec
  final def drop(n: BigInt): LazyList[A] =
    if (n <= BigInt(0)) this else this.tail.drop(n - BigInt(1))
  def take(n: BigInt): LazyList[A] =
    if (n <= BigInt(0)) empty[A]
    else cons(this.head, this.tail.take(n - BigInt(1)))
  def filter_overflow(f: A => Boolean): LazyList[A] =
    this.foldRight(empty[A])((x, xs) => if (f(x)) cons(x, xs) else xs)
  def filter(pred: A => Boolean): LazyList[A] = this match {
    case Empty => empty[A]
    case Cons(h, t) =>
      if (pred(h())) cons(h(), t() filter pred)
      else t() filter pred
  }
}
case object Empty extends LazyList[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](
  hd: () => A,
  tl: () => LazyList[A]) extends LazyList[A]
object LazyList {
  def unit[A](a: A): LazyList[A] = LazyList(a)
  def apply[A](as: A*): LazyList[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) empty[A]
    else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
  def cons[A](h: => A, t: => LazyList[A]): LazyList[A] = {
    // lazy val _h: A = hd
    // lazy val _t: LazyList[A] = tl
    // Cons(() => _h, () => _t)
    Cons(() => h, () => t)
  }
  def empty[A]: LazyList[A] = Empty
  def join[A](ss: => LazyList[LazyList[A]]): LazyList[A] =
    ss.foldRight(empty[A])(_ append _)
  def map2[A, B, C](
    as: LazyList[A],
    bs: LazyList[B])(f: (A, => B) => C): LazyList[C] =
    as flatMap(x => bs flatMap(y => unit(f(x, y))))
  def unfold[S, A](s: S)(f: S => (A, S)): LazyList[A] = {
    val (a0, s0): (A, S) = f(s) 
    cons(a0, unfold(s0)(f))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It strikes me that a major difference between the two is how much stuff is placed on the stackframe with each recursion.

Notice how the `filter()` using `foldRight` is unable to complete the predicate lambda (anonymous function) until the terminus has been reached and the stack starts unwinding.

```
def foldRight[B](z: => B)(f: (A, => B) => B): B = this match {
  case Empty => z
  case Cons(h, t) => f(h(), t().foldRight(z)(f))
}
def filter(f: A => Boolean): LazyList[A] =
  this.foldRight(empty[A])((x, xs) => if (f(x)) cons(x, xs) else xs)
```

In other words, the `foldRight(/*2 parameters*/)` and the `f(/*2 parameters*/)` both go on the stackframe with every iteration.

The `filter()` without `foldRight()`, on the other hand, always completes the predicate before recursing.

```
def filter(pred: A => Boolean): LazyList[A] = this match {
  case Empty => empty[A]
  case Cons(h, t) =>
    if (pred(h())) cons(h(), t() filter pred)
    else t() filter pred
}
```

The uncompleted `cons(/*2 parameters*/)` also goes on the stackframe with the `filter(/*1 parameter*/)`, *but not always.*

The difference between the two, multiplied over thousands of iterations, might explain the results you're getting.

Comment: How would the stack accumulate? I thought the `fibs.filter` will get evaluated to `unfold.filter` which will then get evaluated to `cons.filter` which will then become `Cons.filter` which is when the filter will be evaluated which would call `foldRight` and then `f` returning `unfold.foldRight` thereby cleaning up the stack.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. The `unfold.foldRight` is not returning but continuing to evaluate until it reaches `Cons` at which point `drop` can be called. It is only then that the stack cleans up and probably the gap between 20th and 21st prime number in fibonacci series is big enough for stack to exhaust. Let me know if you think I correctly understood your response and I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed the gap between 21st (571th number in fibonacci series) and 22nd prime (2971th number in fibonacci series) is a huge jump from previous primes. I am hitting the stack overlow trying to read 22nd prime after dropping 21 primes before it. Thanks for your explanation. Accepting your answer.